# How to get video element's current level of loudness

Tags: html5-video, web-audio-api

I do know how to set or get the volume in common sense. Like you set the upper total volume. So if sounds were loud and you lower the volume the volume of the whole clip is shrunk, so loud sounds become quieter and already quite sounds go even below.

I am trying to make animation where, canvas, circle's size changes depending on a volume of video, audio, or microphone, and not based on total volume. I am not making a volume meter.

so basically a sound visualizer for video element.

However, i can't find a property of video element. It's like i can't find the right words, current loudness?!

Links that are helpful:

http://jcla1.com/blog/2012/03/11/web-audio-api-overview-part1/

https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html#AnalyserNode-section

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/

http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001552/index.html

http://webaudioapi.com/samples/

After lots of tries and help form links i have made this...however loudness seem to be at full most of the time not sure if that is true.

http://jsfiddle.net/d4Xqm/10/

http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/d4Xqm/19/

http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/d4Xqm/18/

```
var v= document.getElementById('v'),
    ctx= new webkitAudioContext(),
    src= ctx.createMediaElementSource(v),
    alyz= ctx.createAnalyser(),
    arr= null, l=0, i=0,
    t=true, p=$('.l');


v.addEventListener('play',update);
v.addEventListener('ended',function(){t=false;});

src.connect(alyz);
alyz.connect(ctx.destination);
arr= new Uint8Array(alyz.frequencyBinCount);

function update(){
    if(t) requestAnimationFrame(update);
    alyz.getByteFrequencyData(arr);
    l=0;
    for(i=0; i<arr.length;i++) { l= (l<arr[i])?arr[i]:l; }
    p.text(l);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not making a volume meter"?  That sounds exactly like what you are doing...

Comment: if i go with `$video.volume` it shows the volume as a whole which is useful in making volume modifier/meter like on youtube and other video players. I want to get the data about db of sound which is loudness. Or in other words how loud is the sound right now. Not what is the volume, volume affects the loudness but it is not itself the loudness.

Comment: I think you're mixing up some terms here, which is causing confusion.  A meter simply makes some measurement.  The volume fader (like you see on the bottom of a YouTube) video is not a meter at all.  A meter is exactly what you want to build.  This is typically called a VU meter or peak meter.  Both meters measure loudness, but in different ways.  You can make these using the AnalyserNode in the Web Audio API.

Comment: oh i am sorry for confusion, as i am myself confused. :D...but yes i need exactly that.

Comment: i guess i am near http://jsfiddle.net/d4Xqm/11/

Comment: You're getting close.  Instead of `getByteFrequencyData`, use `getByteTimeDomainData`.  And then you need to realize that the data is unsigned so you have to subtract 128 from every sample (making the pressure levels from -127 to 127).  Then, take the absolute value and you will have a sample of pressure levels at points in time.  From there, you can take the highest in the array (for a peak meter), or apply some complicated math for a VU meter.

Comment: i am confused about what does TimeDomainData represents. time of what..i thought frequency somehow also include time information.

Comment: The most common form of "raw" digital audio is PCM.  PCM is just a set of samples of the current pressure level taken several thousand times per second.  CD quality audio has 44,100 samples taken per second.  These pressure levels make up sample points on a waveform.  This is the **time domain**.  Now, another method of storing digital audio is in the **frequency domain** where you take segments of time (10ms or so) and calculate the amount of sound at varying frequencies (lows to highs).  The frequency data is useful for spectrum analysis, but that isn't what you want to visualize.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d4Xqm/12/ it does look more believable. Although i still dont get it. Are you saying that time domain is basically has higher resolution than frequency domain.

Comment: No, the analysis in the time domain and frequency domain are two different things.  The time domain is what the actual raw samples are in to begin with.  The AnalyserNode gives you a simplified version of them so that you don't have to do math on every single sample for that time period (which is computationally inefficient in JavaScript).  Basically, if you have 44,100 samples, it will give you 2,048 that represent the same waveform.  The frequency domain gives you something else entirely.  The frequency domain is the spectral content of the sound... the levels of each frequency bucket.

Comment: It is true though that the time domain has a much higher sample rate than the frequency domain.  It has to.  You can think of samples in the time domain as being the pressure levels at instantaneous points in time (close enough anyway).  For a frequency to be perceived, you have to have a number of samples so that the period of the wave is measurable.  It is not possible to measure frequency if you only have pressure at one point in time.  You need a sample rate of at least twice the frequency.  (This is the Nyquist frequency.)

Comment: Check this out... in particular, the graph:  http://www.ni.com/white-paper/13042/en/

Comment: thanks a lot, most is clear now....there is something more though...in the video `time domain` graph had multiple lines, one for each frequency. However, there is only one value per time in our time domain returned data. Therefore i assume that one value represents the end value, the amplitude, which is the outcome of interaction of waves (cancel/gain), right? So lets say i wanted to make a graph like that in js. I'd have to divide time domain in 10 ms or so, then take the data from frequency domain and plot the graph based on time from time domain and amplitude/frequency from f domain.

Comment: Yeah, maybe that graph is not the best.  In reality, you're only going to have one line on a time domain graph per channel.  If you wanted to make a time or frequency domain graph, the AnalyserNode does all of the work for you.  Simply plot the values returned, and I think you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What I understand is that you want to make a vu meter, but with circles instead of bars. What you would first need to do is get the average volume of all frequencys from the analyser. Then just use that value as the radius to draw a circle.

I made [a jsfiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/v9j7z/106/) with the code and explaining comments. 
To get the average:

```
var array = new Uint8Array(analyser.fftSize);
analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(array);
var average = 0;
var max = 0;
for (var a of array) {
    a = Math.abs(a - 128);
    average += a;
    max = Math.max(max, a);
}

average /= array.length;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What is this for? `a-128` ?

Comment: @vanowm `getByteTimeDomainData` returns a waveform in `Uint8` that should have positive and negative values. `a - 128` brings it back to a signed distance from the origin (in range `[-128, 127]`). I don't know if this function allows using a signed `Int8Array` directly.